# how to dynamically add the textboxes division in different rows dynamically

Tags: jquery, dynamic

I have a data with three variables like below.

```
ProductName: "FGC 101 127;vSAPC;vSGSN-MME;FGC 101 329/15BV"
Release: "R1A;1.3;v1.2399999;R1A"
Vendor: "Cisco;Cisco;Cisco;Cisco".
```

And in the front end i have a div like below with single row of vendor,productname and release.

[image]

how can i dynamically populate the data in the text boxes on dynamically adding the rows based on the count of product name.
Like in the above i have 4 vendors so the i ahve to add 3 more rows and populate the data accordingly.

Below is my expectation.

[image]

I have tried something like this..I am new to jquery..please help

```js
var responseVnfVendor = response.vnfVendor;
           if(responseVnfVendor !=null && responseVnfVendor.length > 0) {
            var vnfVendorArray = responseVnfVendor.split(";");
               var divCount = 1;
               for (var i = 0; i < vnfVendorArray.length; i++) {
                   if(vnfVendorArray[i]!= "" && vnfVendorArray[i].length > 0) {
                        if(i == 0) {
                               $("#vnfVendor"+divCount).val(vnfVendorArray[i]);
                              // $("#testingTolURL"+divCount).prop('disabled', false);
                              // $("#testingTolFile"+divCount).prop('disabled', true);
                        } else {
                          var divHTML = '<div class="col-md-12" id="vnfSection'+divCount+'">'+
                                '<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">'+
                                '<label class="control-label">Vendor </label>'+
                                '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="vnfVendor'+divCount+'" />'+                
                                '</div>'+
                                '<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">'+
                                '<label class="control-label">Product Name </label>'+
                                '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="vnfProductName'+divCount+'" />'+                
                                '</div>'+
                                '<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">'+
                                '<label class="control-label">Release </label>'+
                                '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="vnfRelease'+divCount+'" />'+  
                                '</div>'+
                                '<div>'+
                                '<button  class="btn btn-action remove" identifier="'+divCount+'" id="vnfDelete'+divCount+'">Delete</button>'+
                                '</div>'+
                                '</div>';   
                             $("#multipleVnf").append(divHTML);
                             $("#noOfVnf").val(divCount);
                                                                                   
                              /* $(".testingTolFile").bind("change",function(){
                                     function_testingTolFile(this);
                               });
                               $(".testingTolClear").bind("click",function(){
                                     function_testingTolClear(this);
                               });
                               $(".testingTolURL").bind("change",function(){
                                     function_testingTolURL(this);
                               });*/
                        }
                       // $("#testingTolFileUploadRemoveButton").hide();
                        divCount++;
                   }                           
               }
               if(vnfVendorArray.length < 10 && vnfVendorArray.length > 1) {
                $("#addVNFButton").show();
                
               } else if(testingTolArray.length == 10) {
                $("#addVNFButton").hide();
                
               }
           }
```

```html
 <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
          <h4 class="panel-title"> <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseThree" class="trigger"> VNF </a> </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree" aria-expanded="true">
          <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="col-md-12 " style="margin:10px 0; float: right"> 
              <button class="btn btn-action  " type="submit" style="margin:3px 0;" id="addVNFButton">+ Add VNF</button>
            </div>
            <div id=multipleVnf>
            <input id="noOfVnf" type="hidden" value="1"/>
            <div  class="col-md-12 " id="vnfSection1">
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                     <label class="control-label">Vendor </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vnfVendor1"  />
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
              <label class="control-label">Product Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vnfProductName1" />
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
              <label class="control-label">Release</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vnfRelease1" />
              </div>             
             </div>
              </div>                    
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output. Your question is unclear, you have posted no effort nor HTML (_div like below?_) and what does _based on count of productname_ mean?

Comment: I am still in process of editing my question and thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56106108/edit) again and then `[<>]` and add relevant HTML, CSS and Javascript in a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented same functionality,
It might be helpful for you 
please refer bellow code

```js
function AddTextbox() {
            var TableRowCount = $('#tblAddTetxbox >tbody >tr').length;

            var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('tr'))
                .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + (TableRowCount + 1))
                .attr("class", 'row');

            TableRowCount += 1;

            var rowId = 'TextBoxDiv' + TableRowCount;
            var rowlblId = 'lbl' + TableRowCount;
            var rowTextboxlId = 'textbox' + TableRowCount;
            var btnUp = "btnUp" + TableRowCount;
            var btnDown = "btnDown" + TableRowCount;
            var btnRemove = "btnRemove" + TableRowCount;


            newTextBoxDiv.after().html(
                '<td class="form-group" style="border-top: 0px solid #ddd !important;text-align:center">' +
                    '<div class="col col-sm-5">' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</td>' +
                '<td class="form-group" style="border-top: 0px solid #ddd !important;">' +
                    '<div class="col col-sm-5">' +
                        '<input type="text" class="form-control class1" name="TitleField" value="" id="' + rowTextboxlId + '" />' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</td>');

            newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#tblAddTetxbox");

            SetRowCount();
    }
    
    function SetRowCount() {
            debugger
            var table = document.getElementById('tblAddTetxbox');
            for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
                var firstCol = table.rows[i].cells[0];
                $("#tblAddTetxbox tbody tr td:nth-child(2) button:nth-child(2)").css('opacity', '');
                $("#tblAddTetxbox tbody tr td:nth-child(2) button:nth-child(1)").css('opacity', '');
                $("#tblAddTetxbox tbody tr:first td:nth-child(2) button:nth-child(1)").css('opacity', '0');
                if (table.rows.length>1) {
                    $("#tblAddTetxbox tbody tr:last td:nth-child(2) button:nth-child(2)").css('opacity', '0');
                }

                if (i===0) {
                    firstCol.innerHTML = "Picture Number";
                }
                else {
                    firstCol.innerHTML = i;
                }
            }
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
                        <div id='TextBoxesGroup' class="col col-sm-12">
                            <table id="tblAddTetxbox" class="table table-borderless">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr class="row">
                                        <th class="col col-sm-4" style="text-align: center;">Picture Number</th>
                                        <th class="col col-sm-8" style="padding-left: 23px;">Title</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody></tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col col-sm-12">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="AddTextbox()" style="margin-left: 100px;">Add</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: ok refer this link, this will be definitely helpful to you https://jsfiddle.net/aaki/hMJEy/1/